# not able to replace string in a file using replace method

Tags: python

Not able to replace the string in file

```
with open("dc_setup.tcl",'r+') as file:
        for line in file:
         if str0 in line:
            line1=line
            print(line1)
            contents=file.read()
            contents=contents.replace(line1,new_str)
            file.seek(0)
            file.truncate()
            file.write(contents)
```

I expect the code to replace string in that file , but I'm getting empty file

Comment: First, it is not known what is `new_str`. Second, if `new_str` is a valid string, you can check the contents by `print(contents)` first before & after the replacement.

Comment: print(contents) does not print anything before and after replacement . And , new_str is a valid string

Comment: If contents are not printed before replacement, then your file could be empty. Check the file contents and isolate the problem by reading the file separately and viewing the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section:

```
file.seek(0)
file.truncate()
file.write(contents)
```

Is overwriting the entire file, not just your current line. Editing text files in place is generally pretty hard, so the usual approach is to write to a new file. You can copy the new file back over the old file once you've finished if you like.

```py
with open("dc_setup.tcl") as infile, open("new_dc_setup.tcl", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if old_str in line:
            line = line.replace(old_str, new_str)
        outfile.write(line)
```